# CSS não acessa o button dentro do if

Tags: php, html, css, button

O CSS está funcionando com o button dentro do `else` porém ele não funciona com o botão situado dentro do `if`. O botão que esta dentro do if refere-se a pagina com o usuário logado e o `else` com o usuário deslogado que esta carregando normalmente as diretrizes feitas no arquivo .css, só gostaria de saber o motivo pelo qual aparenta que ele " não lê o `button` dentro do `if` "

```
?php
    session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="main-wrapper">

                <ul>
                    <li>

                        <a href="index.php">Home</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="nav-login">
                    <?php
                        if (isset($_SESSION['u_id'])) {
                            echo '<form action="includes/logout.inc.php" method="POST">
                        <button type="submit" name="submit">Deslogar</button>
                    </form>';
                        }else{
                            echo '<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
                    <form action="includes/login.inc.php" method="POST">
                        <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Apelido/e-mail">
                        <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Senha">
                        <button type="submit" name="submit">Entre</button>

                    </form>
                    <a href="singup.php">Cadastre-se</a>';
                        }
                    ?>



                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

**CSS do input e do button**

```
header .nav-login form input {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    height: 50%;
    padding: 0% 3%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 30px;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-top-color:#d9d9d9;
    box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    cursor:default;

}
    header .nav-login form input:hover {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    height: 50%;
    padding: 0% 3%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 30px;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-top-color:#d9d9d9;
    box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    cursor:default;
 }

header .nav-login form button {
    float: left;
    width: 17%;
    height: 50%;
    padding: 0% 3%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #696969;
    line-height: 30px;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-top-color:#d9d9d9;
    box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    cursor:pointer;

}

header .nav-login form button:hover {
    float: left;
    width: 17%;
    height: 50%;
    padding: 0% 3%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #000000;
    line-height: 30px;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-top-color:#d9d9d9;
    box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

criei a classe somente para o button e o problema permenece, segue as imagens
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Posta o trecho do css que está sendo usado.

Comment: Postei somente os trechos do button e do input que uso

Comment: Oggi da uma olhada nos comentário que fiz na minha resposta, agora que vi que vc editou a pergunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara rodando o .PHP no local server funcionou normal. Mas só com CSS também da para resolver, basta criar uma classe pro botão e não usar dessa forma `header .nav-login form button`

Sei que não é a resposta exata de pq ele não pega a classe, eu reparei que se vc remover o `<?` o CSS já funciona, porém o PHP não. Mas as vezes essa dica já resolve seu problema se vc puder criar e colocar uma classe no `<button>`

Veja como ficou aqui rodando local: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exemplo da minha sugestão. *(deixei uns comentários no CSS)*

**OBS:** Não mexi em nada apenas coloquei a class direto no botão e não usei o "caminho completo" `.nav-login form button` agora a classe `.btn-login` vai direto no `button`

```css
.btn-login { /* aqui era: "header .nav-login form button" */
    float: left;
    width: 17%;
    height: 50%;
    padding: 0% 3%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #696969;
    line-height: 30px;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-top-color:#d9d9d9;
    box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    cursor:pointer;

}
.btn-login:hover { /* aqui era: "header .nav-login form button:hover" */
    float: left;
    width: 17%;
    height: 50%;
    padding: 0% 3%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #000000;
    line-height: 30px;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-top-color:#d9d9d9;
    box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<form action="includes/logout.inc.php" method="POST">
    <button class="btn-login" type="submit" name="submit">Deslogar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Cara realmente o codigo que voce editou funciona por fora então imagino que esta acontecendo algum tipo de bloqueio no css, será que terei que criar um css a parte?

Comment: Como vc viu na minha resposta o CSS a Parte resolve! Porém ele não explica por que só pega dentro do `else`. Eu fiz um teste e deletando isso **<?php** ele pega o CSS...

Comment: Só agora vi que vc editou. Se vc criou um classe nova e colocou direto no button e não funcionou é pq algum outro CSS está tendo prioridade na sua Classe. Entre trocar classe por **ID** ou colocar o estilo direto na tag tipo **style=" "** para ver se pega.

Comment: Problema resolvido, era realmente essa prioridade, troquei a classe por ID e foi, voce sabe me dizer como altero para respondido? sou novo no stack. Obrigado hugo ajudou muito

Comment: Logo no topo da minha resposta em duas setinhas a esquerda e abaixo delas um " `✔` " basta clicar nesse ícone que a pergunta é marcada como aceita. Isso é bom para manter o site organizado :) que bom que ajudou!